# Updating WordPress to use mysqli instead of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wordpress

I'm updating an old website which has the newest version of WordPress running with some integrated plain PHP code. The PHP code uses the old `mysql_` functions to run db queries and since I'm upgrading the PHP version to 5.6 I have to get rid off those.

I started by simply replacing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` everywhere, however, that leads to the following problem. If you have a query that worked before:

```
mysql_query("SELECT...");
```

Now it throws and error because `mysqli_query("SELECT...")` expects the first parameter to be the connection to the database.

One of the solutions that I can think of is to use `$wpdb` everywhere instead of the plain mysql functions, however, the code has thousands of queries and replacing all of them would turn out to be a bit problematic as the `mysqli_query` functions are usually followed by `mysqli_fetch`, etc.

The solution I'm leaning towards is to somehow obtain the connection from the database that WordPress uses, save it in a variable, let's say `$con` and then just search and replace all of the current `mysqli_query(` with `mysqli_query($con,`. I think that should work but I have no idea how to initialize the `$con` variable as it seems that there's no way to obtain the connection from the `$wpdb` variable? So two questions here:

1. Is there actually a way to initialize the `$con` variable via `$wpdb` or another WordPress method?
2. If the answer is no, then would it be wise to actually initialize `$con` by creating a new mysqli connection to the database and using it to run the queries? (I know the answer is no but hence the lack of solution I might have to get down to this option at the end...)

And bonus question: Can anyone think of a better solution / workaround for this problem from the ones that I already mentioned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, check this [tool](https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool). It can help to migrate from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`.

If not, simply extend **wpdb**:

1. Write a class with getter for "**$dbh**":
2. Use it everywhere instead of base class (this [link](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f0cdd8d0b47dcef51bd95741aaa44cd30fd997eb/wp-includes/load.php#L369)
   can help)

Comment: Thank you, I just figured out how to do it myself. You can actually declare a 'global $wpdb' and then use the '$wpdb->dbh' as first parameter in mysqli_query() etc. Thanks!